# custom menu isnot clickable in admin panel in magento

Tags: magento

I have created a user role name seller. And I have added a custom menu as wallet in the admin panel. I have given resource wallet to the user seller. But when we login to the seller section admin panel,the newly created menu is not clickable.But this menu is working properly in main administrator admin panel.
here is my config.xml file where I have created the menu and given the ACL permission to it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EMoi.png)

Here is the screen shots of the main admin panel and user role admin panel.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfbdd.png)
[enter image description here][3]

Any help is appreciable. Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from images that you attached you have just gave acl to wallet menu as per my knowledge if you need "manage wallet" submenu display when wallet get clicked you also need to give acl to "manage wallet" menu too in config.xml or whichever file.

Once you done with I damn sure your menu will get clickable.

Let me know if you still facing any problem.